# cURL binary location

Tags: php, curl

I have to set up curl on my windows 7 box for development. I've never had to use curl before so I'm lost on the install procedure. I've downloaded the binary executable and unpacked it. There is only the executable and no documentation. I can run the binary from the command prompt with no problems but where do I put this file?

Are there any other libraries that are required to use it with PHP? There is not much documentation on the curl site. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, something that has me a little worried is that I've uncommented the curl option in my php.ini file and when I restart Apache, Apache crashes. Why is this?

> apache error 1067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your use use case completely, but looks like what you need is the libcurl.dll and not the curl executable itself.

Comment: OK, maybe that is my issue. THanks Raam. I'll try that now.

Comment: Err.. Raam, where so I get the libcurl.dll file from? I can't find it on the curl site.

Comment: I think I found a link for the dll file but it only gives me an opt for win32 and I'm on a 64 bit OS. Will the 32 bit work?

Comment: @Jim - The best option is to down load the source and compile it yourself. The read me is excellent and compiling it on windows is a breeze. You can get the source from here http://curl.haxx.se/download.html. Also check this link for the C API http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/. Finally if you intend to use SSL (https endpoints) you will need ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll (Open SSL libraries) as well.

Comment: Thanks Raam. Do I want Cygwin?

Comment: @Jim: No I do not think so. The readme will give you steps on compiling using Visual Studio. For the 64 bit compiler I believe you have to make slight changes to the Makefile that comes with the source.

Comment: Wait... So I have to also install VS as well to compile this?

Comment: @Jim: To compile curl, yes you will need VS. However maybe its not really needed (I am not sure of your use case) so just try downloading a libcurl.dll and trying that. In general you can call a 32 bit dll from a 64 bit context so its worth giving a shot using the 32 bit dll that you have.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not use the cURL standalone command line application, but [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). As such, you need to make sure php_curl.dll can be [found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by your PHP executable.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Should I be using the compiled executable then or libcurl? I'm a bit confused.